# How to get the list of objects from POST request in Json format

Tags: java, json, jersey

I want to get the content JSON body with a list of objects in Java/Jersey in dropwizard

Consider the json body

```
{
    "tag1" : "value",
    "parameter" : [ 
        {
            "name":"value1",
            "content":"value2"
        },
        {
            "name":"value1",
            "content":"value2"
        }
                ]
}
```

I tried to receive the request as

```
  @POST
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public Response insertJob(
      @PathParam("tag1")
          String tag1,
      @JsonProperty("parameter")
          List<RequestParameter> parameter
  ) {

    return Response.ok(parameter).build();

  }
```

but I only get a `"message": "Unable to process JSON"`. When I change the body to only the list

```
[ 
    {
        "name":"value1",
        "content":"value2"
    },
    {
        "name":"value1",
        "content":"value2"
    }
                    ]
```

and the java code to

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public Response insertJob(
          List<RequestParameter> parameter
  ) {
    return Response.ok(parameter).build();

  }
```

I am able to receive the content in the list. How can I get the content if there if there is a tag for the list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a pojo class for the request

```
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import java.util.List;

public class Job {

    private String tag1;

    @JsonProperty("parameter")
    private List<RequestParameter> parameters;

    public String getTag1() {
        return tag1;
    }

    public void setTag1(String tag1) {
        this.tag1 = tag1;
    }

    public List<RequestParameter> getParameters() {
        return parameters;
    }

    public void setParameters(List<RequestParameter> parameters) {
        this.parameters = parameters;
    }
}


public class RequestParameter {

    private String name;
    private String content;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
}
```

Then change controller to this

```
@Path(value = "/job")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response insertJob(
        Job test
) {
    return Response.ok(test).build();

}
```

Here is the output

[image]

Comment: Thanks good job. There was a comma missing in the JSON body . sorry

Comment: Ah. Just see my modified answer :)